# Antonym / opposite of Pastel Color Space (Color Scheme?)

Tags: color, color-theory, rgb, color-spaces

In color spaces we have the regular solid colors like solid red (`#FF0000`), solid green, solid blue, etc. ... Then when we add about 50% white ontop of it, it becomes a "pastel" color space... What about the opposite, if I add 50% black it gets just a dark and a pastel gets light... What are these called? What is the antonym of a pastel color space? Thanks! God bless!

Comment: "Pastel" is usually used when talking about paints and other physical colours, and usually implies a subdued matt finish as well as paler (lighter, less saturated) colours. "Vibrant" or maybe "vivid" or "gloss" might be a sort-of opposite here - but there's more to these than adding black. You can't control how matt or gloss (flat or shiny) the viewer's screen is, so "pastel" vs "vibrant" doesn't work so well RGB for colours on a screen. "Tint" is usually more appropriate than "pastel" (though "pastel" will still be understood).

Comment: What about "[jewel tone](https://thenowherenation.com/blogs/nn-the-journal/colour-theory-jewel-tones)", which is an intense, darker colour?
https://aesthetics.fandom.com/wiki/Colour_Theory#Others
https://www.color-hex.com/color-palette/19155

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why people have to make this complicated. I'd say muted colors are the opposite of pastels. While we think of pastels are loud, bright and vibrant muted colors have a grayer tone.

Comment: I agree, pastels are kind of washed out with white too, like saturation down, brightness up. Muted seems to be saturation down, brightness down. As if they are washed out with black

Comment: Does "dark color" work?

Answer (score 7):

Although I never heard the term 'pastel colour space', it looks like you're talking about *tints*, *tones* and *shades* of a hue, in HSB colour space. The term you're looking for is *shade*.

The pure hue has S(aturation) and B(rightness) each equal to 100%. Adding any amount of white reduces saturation, while keeping the brightness at 100%, yielding a *tint* of the hue. Adding any amount of black reduces brightness, while keeping saturation at 100%, yielding a *shade* of the hue. Lastly, adding both white and black (also known as 'grey') to a pure hue yields a *tone* of the hue.

[image: painter's colour mixing terminology]

[source: Wikimedia commons]